# Performing the colsum based on row values

Tags: r

Hi I have 3 data set with contains the items and counts. I need to add the all data sets and combine the count based on the item names. He is my input.

```
Df1 <- data.frame(items =c("Cookies", "Candys","Toys","Games"), Counts = c( 10,20,30,5))
Df2 <- data.frame(items =c( "Candys","Cookies","Toys"), Counts = c( 5,21,20))
Df3 <- data.frame(items =c( "Playdows","Gummies","Candys"), Counts = c(10,15,20))
Df_all <- rbind(Df1,Df2,Df3)
```

> Df_all

```
      items Counts
1   Cookies     10
2    Candys     20
3      Toys     30
4     Games      5
5    Candys      5
6   Cookies     21
7      Toys     20
8  Playdows     10
9   Gummies     15
10   Candys     20
```

I need to combine the columns based on the item values. Delete the Row after adding the values. My output should be

```
    items   Counts
1   Cookies     31
2    Candys     45
3      Toys     50
4     Games      5
5  Playdows     10
6   Gummies     15
```

Could you help in getting this output in r.

Answer (score 0):

use dplyr:

```
    library(dplyr)
    result<-Df_all%>%group_by(items)%>%summarize(sum(Counts))
    > result
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  items    `sum(Counts)`
  <fct>            <dbl>
1 Candys           45.0 
2 Cookies          31.0 
3 Games             5.00
4 Toys             50.0 
5 Gummies          15.0 
6 Playdows         10.0
```

Comment: Thanks Antonis for your quick response.. it worked

Comment: Good I just made an updated if you want to have your result in a different variable (`result`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tapply

```
tapply(Df_all$Counts, Df_all$items, FUN=sum)
```

what returns

```
  Candys  Cookies    Games     Toys  Gummies Playdows 
      45       31        5       50       15       10
```